# List of Strings to hashmap using Streams

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, java-stream

I have a "," separated String array like this

```
a b c d,
f b h j,
l p o i,
```

I would like this to be converted to a Hashmap like
`HashMap<String, List<String>>` such that second element in list (delimited by space becomes key and the 3rd element becomes value)
So,
This should become

```
b -> c,h
p -> o
```

I want to use Streams API and I think this is the way to go:

```
List<String> entries = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

HashMap<String, List<String>> newMap = entries.stream()
    .collect(line -> {
        if (map.contains(line.split(" ")[1])) {
            // Get existing list and add the element
            map.get(line.split(" ")[1].add(line.split(" ")[1]));
        } else {
            // Create a new list and add
            List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
            values.add(line.split(" ")[1]);
            map.put(line.split(" ")[0], values);
        }
    });
```

Is there any better way? How exactly should I return Hashmap from collect function?

Comment: *Is there any better way?* given that your code doesn't compile, yes, there is a better way. If your question really is that, try to at least post code that compiles and works as expected, and is properly formatted.

Comment: are the elements contained in a list or an array?

Comment: If you really want to find out, the first start by reading the principle of a Collector in the documentation (in fact read everything in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). Then read the documentation of Arrays.stream(), Collectors.groupingBy(), Collectors.mapping() and Collectors.toList(). These  are the pieces you need to use.

Comment: @Aominè : Elements are contained in a list.

Comment: @JBNizet: Modified the code. I have read, but I am not exactly sure how to approach. Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: You can't possibly have read everything I advised you to read in 3 minutes. Read again, carefully, and try combining the methods I talked about in my previous comment. By reading, I mean reading with your brain, and thus understand what you read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Collectors.groupingBy` as shown below to group the inputs (follow the inline comments):

```
String[] inputs = {"a b c d,", "f b h j,", "l p o i,"};
Map<String, List<String>> results =  
     Arrays.stream(inputs).map(s -> s.split(" ")).//splt with space
     collect(Collectors.groupingBy(arr -> arr[1], // Make second element as the key
         Collectors.mapping(arr -> arr[2], // Make third element as the value
                            Collectors.toList())));//collect the values to List
 System.out.println(results);
```

**Output:**

```
{p=[o], b=[c, h]}
```

I suggest you read the API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) to understand how `Collectors.groupingBy` along with `Collectors.mapping`works.

Comment: Thanks. Will surely do!!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the task at hand using a `groupingBy` collector along with `Collectors.mapping` as a downstream collector.

```
Map<String, List<String>> collect =
            myList.stream()
                  .map(s -> s.split(" "))
                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[1],  
                         Collectors.mapping(a -> a[2], Collectors.toList())));
```

output:

```
{p=[o], b=[c, h]}
```

if you want to maintain insertion order then you can specify a `LinkedHashMap` like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> collect =
                myList.stream()
                      .map(s -> s.split(" "))
                      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s[1],
                             LinkedHashMap::new,
                              Collectors.mapping(s -> s[2], Collectors.toList())));
```

output:

```
{b=[c, h], p=[o]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `HashMap` , not just any `Map`

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> output =myList.stream().map(s -> s.split(" "))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy((s) -> s[1],
                    HashMap::new,
                    Collectors.mapping(
                            (s) -> s[2],
                            Collectors.toList())));
```